# Limit currency for one product in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I have enabled two currencies for price in Drupal commerce but I want to enable only one of them for one of products. At this moment I can see both of them in product creation time. Where or how can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no custom module for this, you'll need to alter the product form add/create to adapt to your settings/conditions (simplified logic below):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_commerce_form_commerce_product_ui_product_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Calculate the currency for a given product.
  $currency_code = 'USD';
  $form['commerce_price'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code']['#type'] = 'value';
  $form['commerce_price'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code']['#default_value'] = $currency_code;
  $form['commerce_price'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount']['#field_suffix'] = $currency_code;
}
```

A more complex and customizable option would be to use [hook_field_widget_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info_alter/7) and modify the settings form to add whatever conditions you want for selecting a currency on a product form.